# Restoring .sql backup results in "Error establishing a database connection"

Tags: database, errors, migration, server, localhost

I'm trying to get the database dump (.sql) of a remote site to work with my local setup. Sort of like migrating from remote to local. I've already ftp-ed the site itself, but having problems transferring database.

The database on the remote has "db_name" database name, "username", and "password". I've replicated all those and it **works fine when the database is** ***empty***. I get the setup screen to setup my new site on localhost. So the database connection is working fine.

But soon as I restore the database from the dump (`mysql -u root < dump.sql`) and try to access the site, it throws the "Error establishing a database connection" error.

Why does it throw that error when I know for a fact that couldn't possibly be the problem!

Any ideas?

---

I've captured the logs fresh for both cases for clarity by deleting previous ones and restarting the respective services. As such they're **almost identical** and unfortunately don't reveal anything..

- ## When not working

  [image]

  ^ Not working when the backup is loaded:

  [image]

  - `mysql_error.log`

    ```
    2014-09-21 09:42:43 5008 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
    2014-09-21 09:42:43 5008 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
    2014-09-21 09:42:43 5008 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
    2014-09-21 09:42:43 5008 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
    2014-09-21 09:42:43 5008 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
    2014-09-21 09:42:43 5008 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 20.0M
    2014-09-21 09:42:43 5008 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
    2014-09-21 09:42:43 5008 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
    2014-09-21 09:42:44 5008 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
    2014-09-21 09:42:44 5008 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
    2014-09-21 09:42:44 5008 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.15 started; log sequence number 1626464
    2014-09-21 09:42:44 5008 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
    2014-09-21 09:42:44 5008 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
    2014-09-21 09:42:44 5008 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
    ```
  - `error.log`

    ```
    [Sun Sep 21 09:36:31.214571 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3508:tid 352] AH00455: Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) PHP/5.5.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
    [Sun Sep 21 09:36:31.214571 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3508:tid 352] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Nov 21 2013 20:13:01
    [Sun Sep 21 09:36:31.214571 2014] [core:notice] [pid 3508:tid 352] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\LOCALH~1\\PHP\\EasyPHP\\binaries\\apache\\bin\\eds-httpd.exe -d C:/localhost/PHP/EasyPHP/binaries/apache'
    [Sun Sep 21 09:36:31.217572 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3508:tid 352] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 3536
    [Sun Sep 21 09:36:32.163692 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3536:tid 324] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
    ```
  - `access.log`

    ```
    127.0.0.1 - - [21/Sep/2014:09:36:33 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 423
    127.0.0.1 - - [21/Sep/2014:09:37:18 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 423
    127.0.0.1 - - [21/Sep/2014:09:37:40 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 423
    127.0.0.1 - - [21/Sep/2014:09:42:56 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 423
    127.0.0.1 - - [21/Sep/2014:09:43:29 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 423
    ```
- ## When working

  [image]

  All I have to do is delete the database (or just rename the table)

  [image]

  - `mysql_error.log`

    ```
    2014-09-21 09:59:09 4652 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
    2014-09-21 09:59:09 4652 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
    2014-09-21 09:59:09 4652 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
    2014-09-21 09:59:09 4652 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
    2014-09-21 09:59:09 4652 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
    2014-09-21 09:59:09 4652 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 20.0M
    2014-09-21 09:59:09 4652 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
    2014-09-21 09:59:09 4652 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
    2014-09-21 09:59:09 4652 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
    2014-09-21 09:59:09 4652 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
    2014-09-21 09:59:09 4652 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.15 started; log sequence number 1626484
    2014-09-21 09:59:10 4652 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
    2014-09-21 09:59:10 4652 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
    2014-09-21 09:59:10 4652 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
    ```
  - `error.log`

    ```
    [Sun Sep 21 09:59:09.516571 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 12012:tid 468] AH00455: Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) PHP/5.5.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
    [Sun Sep 21 09:59:09.516571 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 12012:tid 468] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Nov 21 2013 20:13:01
    [Sun Sep 21 09:59:09.516571 2014] [core:notice] [pid 12012:tid 468] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\LOCALH~1\\PHP\\EasyPHP\\binaries\\apache\\bin\\eds-httpd.exe -d C:/localhost/PHP/EasyPHP/binaries/apache'
    [Sun Sep 21 09:59:09.552575 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 12012:tid 468] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 7656
    [Sun Sep 21 09:59:11.559831 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7656:tid 320] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
    ```
  - `access.log`

    ```
    127.0.0.1 - - [21/Sep/2014:10:00:04 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 161
    127.0.0.1 - - [21/Sep/2014:10:00:04 +0530] "GET /wp-admin/install.php HTTP/1.1" 200 4298
    127.0.0.1 - - [21/Sep/2014:10:00:07 +0530] "GET /wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.10.2 HTTP/1.1" 200 93091
    127.0.0.1 - - [21/Sep/2014:10:00:07 +0530] "GET /wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1 HTTP/1.1" 200 7200
    127.0.0.1 - - [21/Sep/2014:10:00:07 +0530] "GET /wp-includes/css/buttons.min.css?ver=3.8.4 HTTP/1.1" 200 5354
    127.0.0.1 - - [21/Sep/2014:10:00:07 +0530] "GET /wp-admin/js/user-profile.min.js?ver=3.8.4 HTTP/1.1" 200 2268
    127.0.0.1 - - [21/Sep/2014:10:00:07 +0530] "GET /wp-includes/js/zxcvbn-async.min.js?ver=1.0 HTTP/1.1" 200 324
    127.0.0.1 - - [21/Sep/2014:10:00:07 +0530] "GET /wp-admin/js/password-strength-meter.min.js?ver=3.8.4 HTTP/1.1" 200 737
    127.0.0.1 - - [21/Sep/2014:10:00:07 +0530] "GET /wp-admin/css/install.min.css?ver=3.8.4 HTTP/1.1" 200 3987
    127.0.0.1 - - [21/Sep/2014:10:00:07 +0530] "GET /wp-admin/images/wordpress-logo.svg?ver=20131107 HTTP/1.1" 200 1521
    127.0.0.1 - - [21/Sep/2014:10:00:08 +0530] "GET /wp-includes/js/zxcvbn.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 698775
    ```

Comment: make sure mysql username/password used in wp-config.php is correct and the user have access to database.

Comment: @Roberthue I have. Like I said, when the database is empty it all works fine.

Comment: Have you checked the `error_log`?

Comment: @TomásCot This might sound noobish but which `error_log`? I'm using EasyPHP on windows and it offers a `mysql_error.log` and apache `error.log` & `access.log`. I've added all their contents for both cases in the question.